# Python parse text for latin alphabet

Tags: python, regex

I have several strings of text containing a mix of characters: Burmese alphabet, Latin alphabets, numbers. I need to be able to break the text up into their separate categories. Here's an example:

```
အေရာင္ဆန္းဆန္းေလး ေတြ ပါတဲ့ Enhancing Eyes shawdow palette ေလးပါ ။ 
Price - 17000 ks. Call 625555555
```

I can identify the numbers with regex

```
re.findall("\d+", data)
```

But I can't figure out how to split the two alphabets. The resulting split doesn't need to be coherent -- I just need 2 separate dumps, a string of Burmese and a string of English. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to go about identifying that?

Comment: What's our expected output?

Comment: Three lists of the different strings. The regex I listed above will give me a list of all numbers in the string (in this case 2). I know need a separate string for just the english characters and a separate string for just the burmese characters

Comment: `[A-Za-z]+` seems to work for me but I'm using a US locale. What locale are you using? Does that not work for you?

Comment: we can't judge without expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like:

```
import re
teststring = """အေရာင္ဆန္းဆန္းေလး ေတြ ပါတဲ့ Enhancing Eyes shawdow palette ေလးပါ ။ 
Price - 17000 ks. Call 625555555"""

Numbers = re.findall("\d+", teststring)
Latin = re.findall("[A-Za-z]+", teststring)
Burmese = re.findall("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]+", teststring)
print Numbers, Latin,
print Burmese
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems you want the output like below.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '''အေရာင္ဆန္းဆန္းေလး ေတြ ပါတဲ့ Enhancing Eyes shawdow palette ေလးပါ ။ 
Price - 17000 ks. Call 625555555'''
>>> re.findall(r'\d+|[^A-Za-z]+|[A-Za-z\s]+', s)
['အေရာင္ဆန္းဆန္းေလး ေတြ ပါတဲ့ ', 'Enhancing Eyes shawdow palette ', 'ေလးပါ ။ \n', 'Price ', '- 17000 ', 'ks', '. ', 'Call ', '625555555']
```